# Which reporter is used for winium like allure reports is used for protractor?

Tags: desktop-application, winium

I would like to test desktop application.
So, I got winium as a best open source to test Desktop Application.
When I gone through online tutorial but unable to find any reporter.
Example - Allure Reports is used in Protractor to test Web Applications.

Answer (score 5):

Reporting tool depends on the artifacts of the unit testing framework (e.g. **NUnit**, **JUnit**, **TestNG**), not on the testing library used (*Selenium*, *Winium* or *Protractor*).

So you can use the same reporting tool for desktop application testing as for the web app.

It might be **Allure**, **ReportPortal**, **ExtentReports** or any other tool that you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Use protractor beautiful report if you are using jasmine 2.0:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-beautiful-reporter

```
npm install protractor-beautiful-reporter
```

**Config:**

```
framework: 'jasmine',
onPrepare: function(){
let HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');
             jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
                baseDirectory: 'reports_new',
                screenshotsSubfolder: 'screenshotsOnFailure',
                takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
                jsonsSubfolder: 'jsonFiles',
                excludeSkippedSpecs: true,
                preserveDirectory: false,
                clientDefaults:{
                showTotalDurationIn: "header",
                totalDurationFormat: "h:m:s",
                gatherBrowserLogs: true
              },
             }).getJasmine2Reporter());
}
```